# Meaning of "они выпали с аппарата"

Tags: перевод, сленг

I had a conversation with my Russian-speaking friend and he used this phrase to describe his impressions of the newly purchased rifle.
"Я тут паре типов своих показал его. Они выпали с аппарата."
I barely understand that he show the rifle, but the other part is complete mystery to me.
Is this some slang gibberish?
What the meaning of this phrase?

Comment: What's the problem with this? Do you know the word *apparatus*?

Comment: well, i have been speking russian for 18 years, and i have never heard such idiom

Answer (score 4):

It's slang all right, but it's not gibberish. Without seeing the context, it can be roughly translated something like

> I showed it to a couple of my mates.  They were totally stumped.

(Note that I am using *showed **it***, as you mentioned a rifle in there).

Word *тип*, apart from its main meaning *type*, *kind* is also used to refer to a person, usually in a somewhat derogatory manner, and usually a man, e.g. *подозрительный тип* could be translated as *twitchy bloke* (although word-for-word means *suspicious man*).

*Выпасть с аппарата* is one of a large number of slang phrases meaning to be totally stumped.  Some other ones you may encounter are *выпасть в осадок*, *офигеть* и т д.

Comment: There must be discussed a cellular or some other device. But *аппарат* may mean *penis*, depending on context. Also, the word *тип* in this meaning has stress on the ending syllable.

Comment: @КуЪ I agree, there is some dependency on context here, hence I put "Without seeing the context..."  As for the stressed syllable, I don't understand why it's on the ending one.  I'd say it should be _ти́пов_

Comment: Возможно, зависит от региона. Большинство моих знакомых говорят *тому типу́, эти типы́*, придавая таким образом оттенок пренебрежительного отношения объекту обсуждения, при этом речь в целом, как правило, изобилует сленгом. В других ситуациях, особенно в случаях с устоявшимися словосочетаниями, такими, как *подозрительный тип* – да, ударение на *и*.

Comment: Я думаю "аппарат" здесь в своем обычном значении - синоним устройства. Т.е. аппарат = ружье. "Выпали с аппарата" = были в восторге от устройства (т.е. от ружья). Об этом, кстати, Putnik тоже написал.

Comment: Yeah, probably just in your town or your friend's speech. Never really heard anyone moving stress from its usual position — which is not surprising, given that "тип" as applied to people is not in much use these days. So.. no, in Moscow and, probably, central region in general, "тип" will have the same stress regardless of its meaning.

Answer (score 2):

"Я тут паре типов своих показал его. Они выпали с аппарата."
I let the guys check that thing out. They said it was sick.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add a bit to Aleks G words.

`Выпали с аппарата` I consider as `they were impressed much by the rifle`. Here `c` stands for `из того, что собой представляет` or `от вида (механизма)`

Please nothe that the first person boasted of the rifle, so I expect there really is something impressive, and the impression is stressed by the word `Выпали` which is quite rarely used alone.

Comment: *выпасть в осадок* не так чтобы и необычное или редкое счетание, сами по себе ситуации не настоько часты )

Comment: @MolbOrg yes if we're speaking about `выпасть в осадок` as a fixed phrase, not the word `выпасть` alone.

Comment: mm yes, I got your point, rifle is аппарат, агрегат, Вещь и тд. Меня предложение несколько поставило в тупик, действительно такое сочетание употребления *выпасть* не частый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

> "Я тут паре типов своих показал его. Они выпали с аппарата."

As far as I understand, the OP author understands the first sentence (though barely). Just in case I will still explain it: In this context "типы" - means "guys", "своих" means that the speaker knew them before. "Тут" rather means "recently" than "here".

The second sentence is more interesting. It looks like it is a new kind of slang. "Аппарат" in this context means "летательный аппарат", so the literal meaning of the phrase is that "they fell down from the plane". "Аппарат" on the pilot's slang meant "plane" since long time ago. See [here](http://z25t.ru/stats/46-slovar-aviacionnogo-zhargona-slenga.html) for example, in the end of "Жаргонные фразы" section. In 2009 there was a stunning [news](http://omskpress.ru/news/3837/pilot_vypal_iz_apparata/) that in Omsk region one of pilots of a glider used for agricultural spraying fell down from the plane when the plane was 300 meters above the ground. Here we can see that newspapers use jargon words ("аппарат") as if they were common use.
The news was [discussed](http://delta.wtr.ru/archive/1520.shtml) on internet quite a lot and in person I guess, too. So, most likely it was then when it entered the youth's slang. The meaning of the internet discussion is that it is hardly possible to fall down from the glider because there are a lot of safety features. Pilots do not fall from the plane normally.

When the phrase entered the slang it changed its meaning from literal to figurative. Something like: "they were so amazed that totally lost control and fell from the plane".

Comment: In the book referenced, the meaning of the phrase is literal. It is plausible that phrase could become popular in the figurative sense from something like that, but such connection is to be established. Also, the phrase “летательный аппарат” is no jargon. It is normal [technical term](http://slovari.yandex.ru/летательный%20аппарат/БСЭ/Летательный%20аппарат/) (such as “flying machine” in English).

Comment: @theUg: 1) I did not say that "летательный аппарат" is a slang. 2) Yes, I implied that from literal sense the phrase transitioned to the figurative. I should add it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: `летательный аппарат` - absolutely not. There's no reasonable context for this.